# Change size of Foundation Icon Fonts 3?

Tags: css, icons, zurb-foundation, foundation-icon-fonts, foundation-icon-fonts-3

I try to change the size of my icon download here :

http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3

In the documentation they say :

```
<i class="fi-[icon]"></i>
```

So for exemple i use :

But the size is 16px and they don't say how can we change...

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you are using the heart Icon.

The css may looks like that:

```
.fi-heart {
   font-size: 20px
}
```

Use what ever size you like instead of the 20px.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look in font icon foundation download file.
You need to inspect element there in preview.html of one of icon.

```
<i class="step fi-power size-72"></i>
```

Please add size between 12 and 72.

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna use more icons with exact same appearance then in the downloaded css change the font-size to inherit and create a class in your local css with the required font-size, you can apply this to any property.

```
.fi-yen:before,....,.fi-zoom-in:before,.fi-zoom-out:before 
{
   font-family: "foundation-icons";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
   text-transform: none;
   line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-size:inherit;    #add this
}
```

and in your local css file

```
.icons{
   font-size:25px;
 }
```

now you are good to use this class in addition to your icon class. so your html will look something like this

```
<span class="icons"><i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i></span>
<span class="icons"><i class="fi-social-twitter"></i></span>
```